# ¿Como usar correctamente el evento click en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, html5, web

Buen dia
No entiendo cual es el error,lo que quiero es que al tocar en **Hola** cambie a **Mundo**

```js
function cambiardiv(){
    var i=document.getElementById("a").click="Mundo"
}
window.onload=cambiardiv;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="eventoclick_ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">Hola</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Tambien me gustaria saber si es posible que volviendo a tocar mundo el div cambie a hola,y asi en una especie de bucle...

Comment: Lo debes hacer usando un eventListener o usando jQuery, y lo de cambiar cada click es posible solo debes hacer un if que verfique el contenido del div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que buscas es llamar el evento bajo un script externo, puedes usar el método `addEventListener` para agregar el evento de click a tu elemento, y la función que se va a ejecutar cuando se gatille dicho evento.

## Respuesta original

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">Hola</div>

    <!-- Tu script externo debería estar aquí, casi terminando el elemento body --> 
    <script src="eventoclick_ext.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript (`eventoclick_ext.js`)

```
/* Elemento DIV que cambia su texto */
var a = document.getElementById("a");

/* Se agrega el evento al elemento */
a.addEventListener("click", changeText);

/* Función que se gatilla al hacer click en el elemento DIV */
function changeText() {
    if (a.innerHTML == "Hola") {
        a.innerHTML = "Mundo";
    } else if (a.innerHTML == "Mundo") {
        a.innerHTML = "Hola"; 
    }
}
```

## Adicional: Si el script JS se ubica en el elemento `<head>`

### HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="eventoclick_ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body function>
    <div id="a">Hola</div>
</body>
</html>
```

### JavaScript (`eventoclick_ext.js`)

```
/* Al cargar la página se gatilla el listener */
window.addEventListener("load", main);

function main() {
    /* Elemento DIV que cambia su texto*/
    var a = document.getElementById("a");

    /* Se agrega el evento */
    a.addEventListener("click", changeText);

    /* Función que se gatilla al hacer click en el elemento DIV */
    function changeText() {
        if (a.innerHTML == "Hola") {
            a.innerHTML = "Mundo";
        } else if (a.innerHTML == "Mundo") {
            a.innerHTML = "Hola"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Si quiero dejar el script externo en el head,cual seria la manera correcta de usar window.onload?

Comment: Si quieres dejar tu script en el `<head>` también puedes usar el evento `addEventListener`, tomando en cuenta que el evento que debes agregar en dicho método es el evento `load`. El resto del código va a ir en una función principal, que se va a ejecutar cuando se gatille dicho evento. Lo voy a agregar como adicional a la respuesta, aunque lo recomendado es que tu script vaya casi al final del elemento `<body>`.

Comment: uno no debe usar `innerHTML` porque  puedes provocar injeccion de codigo malicioso con en vez, debes usar `innerText` o `textContent`

Answer (score 4):

Se puede resolver asi:

```
<div id="a" onclick="cambiarDiv();">Hola</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    function cambiarDiv(){

        var contenido = document.getElementById('a').innerHTML;
        if (contenido == "Hola") {
            document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = "Mundo";
        }else{
            document.getElementById('a').innerHTML = "Hola";
        }

    }

</script>
```

Comment: Lo que yo estoy buscando es no usar el evento en la etiqueta html.  
Se puede llamar a la funcion con .onclick o .click desde un archivo externo?

Comment: Si, asi como lo puse tambien funciona haciendolo desde un archivo externo.

Comment: este codigo tiene malas practicas. Para empezar nunca se debe usar `innerHTML` sino `innerText` o `textContent` y segundo el uso de javascript inline es considerado un alto riesgo de seguridad por permitir a cualquier cliente ejecutar codigo de terceros. Uno nunca debe de utilizar los eventos desde HTML sino con el metodo `addEventListener()` ref. mdn

Answer (score 3):

Lo que debes hacer es indicar por medio del selector Jquery $ que al `div` con id = a al momento de darle click realizara la inserción de texto dependiendo de lo que tenga escrito en el momento.

```js
$('#a').click(function(){
    var i=document.getElementById("a");
    var temp = i.innerHTML;

     if(temp=="Hola"){
        i.innerHTML = "Mundo";
     }else{
        i.innerHTML = "Hola";
    };
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="eventoclick_ext.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="a">Hola</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Lo que yo estoy buscando es no usar el evento en la etiqueta html.
Se puede llamar a la funcion con .onclick o .click desde un archivo externo?

Comment: @Ale Ya edite la respuesta con lo que deseas.

Comment: @Ale y puedes usarlo normalmente desde un archivo externo.

Comment: uno no debe usar `innerHTML` porque  puedes provocar injeccion de codigo malicioso con en vez, debes usar `innerText` o `textContent`

Answer (score 0):

```
window.onload = start;

function start() {
    var tocame = document.getElementById("a");
    tocame.onclick = cambiardiv;

    function cambiardiv() {
        var mensaje = tocame.innerHTML;
        mensaje = mensaje == "Hola" ? "Mundo" : "Hola";
        document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = mensaje;
    }
}
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a la pregunta. Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.